# Oracle: Comparing string columns from two different table without a primary key to find match/unmatched string

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql

I have two tables, and we want to compare the two string columns from these tables. there is no primary key in these table to match in the where clause. Tables are as below:
The compare should ignore :

1. IGNORE SPACES  AT ANY PLACE IN THE STRING 2) IGNORE CASE SENSITIVE

[image]

## OUTPUT WANT:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly; sample data from line #1 - 16. Query you might need begins at line #17.

```
SQL> with
  2  tab1 (col) as
  3    (select 'mg/kl'     from dual union all
  4     select 'k/mg'      from dual union all
  5     select 'l/g/kg'    from dual union all
  6     select 'umol_Ulp'  from dual union all
  7     select '10*12_/KG' from dual union all
  8     select 'a/L/G'     from dual
  9    ),
 10  tab2 (col) as
 11    (select '10*12_/kg' from dual union all
 12     select '1/L/G'     from dual union all
 13     select 'PG/7@R'    from dual union all
 14     select 'KG/CM/L'   from dual union all
 15     select 'l/g/kg'    from dual
 16    )
 17  select a.col, b.col,
 18    case when lower(a.col) = lower(b.col) then
 19              'exists in both tables ' ||
 20              case when a.col = b.col then 'and exact match'
 21                   else 'but different'
 22              end
 23         when a.col is null then 'missing in table 1'
 24         when b.col is null then 'missing in table 2'
 25    end differences
 26  from tab1 a full outer join tab2 b on lower(a.col) = lower(b.col);

COL       COL       DIFFERENCES
--------- --------- -------------------------------------
mg/kl               missing in table 2
k/mg                missing in table 2
l/g/kg    l/g/kg    exists in both tables and exact match
umol_Ulp            missing in table 2
10*12_/KG 10*12_/kg exists in both tables but different
a/L/G               missing in table 2
          KG/CM/L   missing in table 1
          PG/7@R    missing in table 1
          1/L/G     missing in table 1

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: I am just verifying the queries and will MARK IT as a solution soon..............

Comment: One Question to Expert: Does it matter in the FULL JOIN the position of T1 AND T2 ? I Mean "On t1.str = t2.str" VS "On t2.str = t1 .str" return the same results ??? –

Comment: It doesn't matter, you'll get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `full outer join` with `upper` and `replace` function in join condition as follows:

```
Select t1.str, t2.str,
       Case when t1.str is not null and t2.str is not null then 'exist in both table'
             when t1.str is not null then 'missing in table2'
             Else 'missing in table1'
       End as differences
From table1 t1 full join table2 t2
  On upper(replace(t1.str,' ','') = upper(replace(t2.str,' ','')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tejash for your help again but i already tried FULL OUTER JOIN but not sure why i am getting some values returned which exists in BOTH the tables but in the output it is showing missing in table 2.....Not sure why? Does FULL OUTER Join has any issue.....

Comment: Can you show me the exact result that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

try the below SQL once and see if works. Otherwise can you please share those values which it says 'missing in table 2' even though it exists in both the tables?

```
Select t1.str, t2.str,
       Case when nvl(t1.str,'X') != 'X' and nvl(t2.str,'X') != 'X' then 'exist in both table'
             when nvl(t1.str,'X') != 'X' then 'missing in table2'
             Else 'missing in table1'
       End as differences
From table1 t1 full join table2 t2
  On upper(trim(t1.str)) = upper(trim(t2.str))
```

Comment: Thanks Shantanu, I was matching with incorrect list. Your solution with FULL JOIN works....thanks a lot dear...........

Comment: One Question to Expert:                                                                                        
 Does it matter in the FULL JOIN the position of T1 AND T2 ?                                     I Mean  "On t1.str = t2.str"  VS                                                                                  "On t2.str = t1 .str"    return the same results ???

Comment: It will not matter. you should get the same result.